# Accessing X$ share on a personal computer

Tags: windows-7, login, smb, unc

I need to access some of my hard drives on my desktop PC from my laptop without setting a public share folder. I run Windows 7 Ultimate on both

When I try to connect to \mycomputer\e$ it asks me for password (it's OK), but when I type "MYCOMPUTER\DJ Echelon" as user name and my local admin password it refuses to log in.

I usually use this way of logging in (with my company's domain) when accessing my work laptop's hard drive, and it works. I simply specified the domain name only because Windows wants me to log in inside my laptop's domain (which actually is not a domain, Windows just says "Domain: MYLAPTOP" so I tried to replace it).

What am I missing?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Microsoft [kb947232](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947232):

> By default, Windows Vista and newer versions of Windows prevent local accounts from accessing administrative shares through the network.

That kb also has a workaround to enable administrative shares if you do want to enable them.